# Use v-for to make b-card grid with image & href link

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js

I am trying to make a 3 by 3 card grid for a page. Each card has a unique image in the assets folder, as well as some text. Each card also links to another page. when I reload the page it just states "cannot read property undefined". Does anyone know how to resolve this? It only works without the href and image elements.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-row class="mt-5" v-for="index in data.length / 3" :key="index">
      <b-col cols="4" v-for="(item, idx) in data.slice((index - 1) * 3, (index - 1) * 3 + 3)" :key="idx">
        <b-card class="card-item">
          <img :src= "$[value].jpeg" {{ item.image }}/>
           <href= "$[value] {{ item.value }}/>
          <p class="secondary-text">{{ item.text }}</p>
        </b-card>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
import CardGrid from '../components/CardGrid.vue';
export default {
  name: 'Education',
  components: { CardGrid },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$auth.loggedIn);
    console.log(this.$auth.user);
  },
  data() {
    return {
      grid: [
        {image: 'url', text: `some text`}, 
        {image: 'url', text: `some text`}, 
        {image: 'url', text: `some text`}, 
        {image: 'url', text: 'some text'}, 
        {image: 'url', text: `some text`}, 
        {image: 'url', text: 'some text'}, 
        {image: 'url', text: 'some text'}, 
        {image: 'url', text: 'some text'}, 
        {image: 'url', text: 'some text'}
        ]
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, What is `:src= "$[value].jpeg"` value in here? I think it should be `item.value`. Also, you can inspect the link in dev tools to see whether the image link is properly prepared.

Comment: When you reload the page your data store is probably reset. Are you using vuex?